# Random number generator, how to get random numbers that are not the same

Tags: python, random

I am making a random number generator but I do not want the numbers over again. so for example

[1,2,3,4] is perfect - 
[1,1,2,4] is not what I want because a number recurring.

I have looked on here and no one has the answer to the problem I am searching for, in my logic this should work but I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I am new to python and I saw a couple questions like mine but none with the same problem

```
import random, timeit
random_num = random.randint(1,10)
cont_randomized_num = random.randint(1,10)
tries = 0
start = timeit.default_timer()
num_guess = 0
stored_numbers = []

while cont_randomized_num != random_num:
    if cont_randomized_num == stored_numbers:
        cont_randomized_num = random.randint(1,10)
    elif cont_randomized_num != stored_numbers:
        print(num_guess)
        stored_numbers.append(cont_randomized_num)
        print(stored_numbers)
        cont_randomized_num = random.randint(1,10)
        tries +=1

print()
print()
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print(random_num)
print('Number of tries:',tries)
print('Time elapsed:',stop)
input('press ENTER to end')
```

I guess I did not make myself clear enough.
I want to generate a random number = ANSWER
I want a second number generated to try and match the ANSWER, if it is not the ANSWER then STORE it somewhere. If the second generated number is generated a second time and it is the same as the first time it was generated I want it to skip and generate a new one. Keep this going until the second generated number is equal to the first number generated.

---

I have figured it out (finally) here is the code that is not over complicated and have nothing to do with any answer or critique given! This is what I have been asking for this entire time.

```
import random
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()
stored_numbers = []
cont_random = random.randint(1,10)
random_num = random.randint(1,10)
times_guessed = 0

while random_num not in stored_numbers:
    if cont_random in stored_numbers:
        cont_random = random.randint(1, 10)
    elif cont_random not in stored_numbers:
        print(cont_random)
        stored_numbers.append(cont_random)
        cont_random = random.randint(1, 10)
        times_guessed += 1

print('Answer has been guessed!')
print('Stored numbers',stored_numbers)
print()
print()
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time elapsed:',stop)
print('Times guessed -', times_guessed)
print('The random number:',random_num)
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: The simple and expedient way to solve this is to have a function that checks if the elements in your list are all unique, and to replace a duplicate with a random number until the list is unique.

Comment: Like I said, I am new so I do not know how to do that.

Comment: If you can Google and can break a problem into parts, you can do anything. :)

Comment: "If the second generated number is generated a second time and it is the same as the first time it was generated [...]" --- the second time a number is generated, it's already guaranteed to be equal to the first time.  That's how you know it's the same number in the first place.

Comment: I am going to explain it one more... I want a number randomly generated say its 50, and a second number to be continuously generated until it matches 50. That code is easy here is what I am truly asking. How do I make sure the second number generated is not the same twice? I do not want the second number to generate 40 twice or whatever. I want each number randomly generated to be different than a previously generated number. I want this printed out one by one.

Comment: "...have nothing to do with any answer or critique given!" --- The fact that literally _no one_ was able to figure out what you meant, despite your many comments and edits, is strong evidence that your method of explaining what you want needs improvement.  Note that one answer has _all_ the upvotes, even though it didn't solve your problem --- that's because many people could see that it correctly answered the question you _actually asked_.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase if you read my edit it explains this. I tried to explain but not well enough... =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, you can add more functionality to it if you want by adding more code in the loop.

```
import random, timeit

def main():
    tries = 0
    NUMBER_OF_RANDOMS = 4
    stored_numbers = []
    start = timeit.default_timer()

    while len(stored_numbers) != NUMBER_OF_RANDOMS:
        current = random.randint(1,10)
        tries += 1
        if current not in stored_numbers:
            stored_numbers.append(current)

    stop = timeit.default_timer() - start
    print 'Number of tries:', tries
    print 'Time elapsed:', stop
    print stored_numbers

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Does this do what you were wanting? I believe you do unnecessarily complicated code.

Comment: This is what I was looking for more or less, yes this is complicated but it is what I wanted. Thank you for your time! Programming is finding out how many ways something can be done correct? Even if it is not the best way!

Comment: @TylerG. - Python programming is about finding the right way to do things. ["There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 If I dont try new things how am I suppose to learn how not to do it? Doing it the same way as everyone else (since I am not selling it, using it for commercial use, or working for a company) there is no reason not to try new things.

Comment: Learning how to do things in different ways is very good for learning, but the right way is when you're concerned with efficiency or commercial use. If you think this is a solution, you should mark it as so. I'm trying to get my reputation high enough to comment on other posts. It would be much appreciated, else I can revise it if you wish for more.

Comment: You have been helpful, though I do not believe anyone truly understands what I am trying to do.

Comment: @AustinDerrow-Pinion I figured it out on my main post, please look at the edit.

Comment: Your "elif" condition is not needed, because if the condition (cont_random in stored_numbers) is true, then in all other cases (cont_random not in stored_numbers) will be true. Therefore you can just replace that with an "else" statement. On large scale, that would improve efficiency since the computer doesn't have to evaluate one more condition each time it loops.

Answer (score 5):

Use `random.sample()` instead of populating the list one by one (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```
random.sample(range(10), 5)
>>>> [5, 9, 1, 6, 3]
```

`random.sample()` needs to be fed a list (or any iterable, really) to choose a subset from. Here, I gave it a list of the first 10 numbers starting from 0.

Comment: How do I make this into what I am trying to do which is spout a number then check, how do I use a populated list to do that?

Comment: @TylerG. No, Tyler, the point of this solution is to completely replace the need for a function :) You just wanted a list of unique random numbers? This solution will give that to you directly.

Comment: Its a good solution but not the one I am after, I am after a number being spout off then checked if it has been used before and if so, try it against the original random number. This might not be the best way but it is the way I want to do it.

Comment: @TylerG. I don't understand. You want a series of random numbers that have never been used before to 'try it against' another number? What does that mean?

Comment: @TylerG. - Is it for homework? Homework questions often ask that you do things in suboptimal ways.

Comment: @Liongold I mean to get a random number, check to see if it is used, then if it isnt store it. repeat this till the solution has been found.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 no this is just for my own enjoyment =)

Comment: @TylerG.  What do you mean by "the solution"?  What do you mean by "store"?  These things should all be _clearly_ defined and _in your question_.  Please [edit] your question to include _all_ your requirements, in simple and clear language --- don't use phrases like "spout off" or "try it against", because we don't know what those mean.  Don't even talk about "the solution" until you've defined it... _you_ know what you want, but we don't.

Comment: @TylerG. But then what's the difference between just generating numbers in order from zero? Since you insist, however, you can do `store = []; random_num = random.randint(1,10); if random_num not in store: store.append(random_num)` and have it repeat using a while/for loop until satisfied. (The semicolons are only there to include breaks and aren't part of code).

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase You will be happy to know that I did update it =)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I figured it out on my main post, please look at the edit.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I figured it out on my main post, please look at the edit.